# Proof that $\bigcup X$ is in bijection with $X$.

Tags: set-theory

Let $X$ be an infinite set such that for all $x \in X$, exists an injection $f_x: x \to X$. Proof that $\bigcup X$ is in bijection with $X$.

By definition, $y \in \bigcup X \iff \exists x \in X, \, y \in x$.

My attempt: By Cantor-Schroder-Bernstein theorem,  it's sufficient showing that exists an injection $\bigcup X \to X$ and an injection $X \to \bigcup X$.
If I take $f \doteq \bigcup_{x \in X} f_x$, we have a function $f: \bigcup X \to X$. However, this is not injective.

By the other side, I couldn't see any injection from $X$ in $\bigcup X$.

Help?

Comment: Say $X=\{A: A\subset \mathbb Q\}$ (where $\mathbb Q$ is the set of all rationals, though I realize any countably infinite set would work in place of $\mathbb Q$). Then $|X|=2^{\aleph_0}=\mathfrak c$ and $\bigcup X =\mathbb Q$ so $|X|=\aleph_0$. This seems to be a counterexample, for the desired direction of an injection from $X$ to $\bigcup X$. Am I missing something, or is the problem misstated?

Comment: I found the description of this question to be confusing.  I think it should be stated that you are treating each member of set $X$ as a set itself.  Note that @Mirko and Eric Wofsey's counter-examples go away if you assume distinct members of $X$ are disjoint, that is, $x \cap y = \phi$ whenever $x, y \in X$ and $x \neq y$.  In this case, the statement you are trying to prove seems to be true if you can use existence of a bijection between $X$ and $X \times X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result you're trying to prove is not true.  For instance, let $X=\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$, the set of all subsets of $\mathbb{N}$. Then $X$ is uncountable, but $\bigcup X=\mathbb{N}$ is countable.

It is true that there is an injection $\bigcup X\to X$, but as you observed, your construction does not work since your $f$ need not be injective.  As G. Sassatelli commented, another more minor problem is that your $f$ may not even be a function, since the domains of the functions $f_x$ may overlap.

Here's one thing you can do instead.  Let $<$ be a well-ordering on $X$.  For each $a\in\bigcup X$, let $g(a)$ be the $<$-least element of $X$ such that $a\in g(a)$.  Define $f:\bigcup X\to X\times X$ by $f(a)=(g(a),f_{g(a)}(x))$.  I will leave it to you to verify that this $f$ is an injection.  Composing $f$ with a bijection $X\times X\to X$ then gives an injection $\bigcup X\to X$.

Comment: Ah, I did not catch that!

Comment: @Eric : I suspect that the question was implicitly assuming the different members of set $X$ are themselves _disjoint_ sets (see my comment above), in which case the statement is true.  In that case I notice your last paragraph seems similar to what I was suggesting, but with the disjoint set assumption you no longer need the well ordering aspect you describe.